Tkinter different behaviours for alpha using terminal and script
I'm trying to create an interface that has some transparency. I know that should be straightforward, but I'm facing a confusing bug.
If I run the following code in the terminal:
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
root.mainloop()

It works fine, and the window is created perfectly with the dimensions and transparency I requested. However, if I run a script like this (on the same environment):
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
    root.mainloop()

It doesn't work. The dimensions are applied to the new window, but not the transparency.
I tried wm_attributes and attributes. Both do not work when running python script.py.
Am I crazy? Why is there any difference in behaviour?
The environments are the same; I'm using Python 3.13, and no other dependencies are involved. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 using x11.

Edit:
Here is proof I'm running on the same environment.

And just so the terminal is clear folder git status environment laptop battery

When I test both code pieces of code on terminal and script, I get both windows transparent. Please verify that you are running the code on terminal and script with the same python environment.

I just added proof that they are indeed in the same environment with the same Python. The yellow text in the screenshot is the environment. I'm using the same environment in both. I changed the code a little to have the title be script.

Try running: python -c 'import tkinter as tk; root = tk.Tk(); root.geometry("400x400"); root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5); root.mainloop()'. Also check that both pythons are the same version. This is probably a bug in tkinter, so what OS/Window manager are you using?

Thanks for your comment @TheLizzard. I edited the question with the OS version and window manager. I'm running Ubuntu with x11 (not sure about x11 though). I ran loginctl show-session $(loginctl | grep $(whoami) | awk '{print $1}') -p Type to discover. When running python -c 'import tkinter as tk; root = tk.Tk(); root.geometry("400x400"); root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5); root.mainloop()' it did also not apply the transparency. Is there something I could do to enforce the terminal behaviour?

So, thanks to the comments, I managed to find an answer. When setting attributes like -alpha, some window managers delay applying them until the window is fully realized and shown. By adding root.update_idletasks() before root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5) my script now behaves like the terminal.
The updated code is now:
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
    root.mainloop()

Thanks for the help! I am leaving the answer here in case someone faces the same issue in the future.

Given @TheLizzard comments, I think a better solution would be:
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    root.after_idle(root.attributes, "-alpha", 0.5)
    root.mainloop()

So, it waits for the window to be idle.

Can you try root.after_idle(root.attributes, "-alpha", 0.5) instead? Maybe a patch to tkinter so that .attributes("-alpha") calls wait until the window is drawn is in order.

That works perfectly.

Probably: In interactive mode, Tkinter-loop has window-lifecycles full control. The second code has an additional level of encapsulation(if __name__ == "__main__":), which may lead to timing issues. Create a function and use with root.after
import tkinter as tk

def set_transparency():
    root.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    root.after(0, set_transparency)  # Ensure this line
    root.mainloop()


That also works, but I think since it is a problem from the window managers, just setting 0 might not work if it takes longer for the root to appear. Probably, the solution @TheLizzard gave will be better since it waits until the window is idle.
